# Wordpress URL error for links

Tags: database, wp-admin, domain

I have the following in my database

```
siteurl    subdomain.example.com
home       subdomain.example.com
```

and when I attempt to go to some pages, the pages go to `subdomain.example.com/services/subdomain.example.com`

Is there any reason why this would happen? I can't get into the wp-admin either because of this weird error and I can't understand why it would be happening?

I've attempted to change the values in the database with `http://` prepended already also.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Check Your .htaccess , might be you used redirection

Comment: my htaccess is
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: Htaccess is ok... Try to rename your theme and plugin folder(If you have any redirection plugin than rename that plugin)

Comment: ive added in the stuff as described in the other answers but the external photo's etc are still having this issue...

Comment: Do you have any cache plugin or folder, if yes than rename it, and add define('RELOCATE',true); above define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://subdomain.example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://subdomain.example.com' ); check if you can get in the admin section/.

Comment: nope not plugins, its really odd as to why its doing this now... i can't work out why, it keeps going like `example.subdomain.com/example.subdomain.com/image1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by **http://** in front of **site_url** and **home** in the **wp_options** table of your database.

You can try adding below in **wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://subdomain.example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://subdomain.example.com' );
```

For more details follow this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) hope this will help.

Comment: May be your permalink settings have something to update, As you said you can go to admin pages try flush_rewrite_rules(); to your theme's functions.php, load the page, and them remove it. It is very inefficient to have that run on every page load.

Comment: so i've done this and its got better, however the external resources (such as photos) still have the path to the issues described above..

i've also rewritten the htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Try defining those things by editing wp-config.php file and adding these lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com/');
```

Comment: so i've done this and its got better, however the external resources (such as photos) still have the path to the issues described above..

Comment: If you have absolute url-s (example: http://subdomain.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/abc.jpg) in your content/posts/pages/custom fields, you will have to rewrite them all, you could do that with a plugin (the bad thing is that you will only be able to rewrite from subdomain.example... to anothersubdomain.anotherexample so it wont be flexible).
The best solution is to keep this in mind beforehand and all your links in your content could be relative (example: /wp-content/uploads/2017/10/abc.jpg).
You could also try to change the url-s in DB using mysql queries, but that is Risky!